How to automatically open msi afterburner hardware monitor window?
I use MSI Afterburner only to monitor my CPU and GPU.
Currently, for me to be able to view the hardware monitor window, I need to follow 2 steps:

Click on the MSI Afterburner icon on the taskbar
Click on monitor icon to open the monitor hardware

I wonder if anyone knows how I can get this hardware monitor window to be automatically opened (minimized to the taskbar) when I start Windows?

